# Using Github Actions Script to Continuously Update React App Deployment via SSH Server

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, create-react-app, github-actions, vps

Goal: update react app using github actions to create a new build after repository updates

Context: app is currently working on my VPS.

Question: I have found this base script

```
name: Deploy

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Copy repository contents via scp
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      env:
        HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        KEY: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
      with:
        source: "."
        target: "YOUR BUILD DIRECTORY"

    - name: Executing remote command
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        KEY: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
        script:
```

My secrets work and I am able to connect to my server via SSH.
However, as my build is already up and running, copying the repo into the directory is met with errors

```
Cannot open: file exists
Cannot open: permission denied
```

The former is due to the existence of the app. The latter is due to the SSH accessing a non-root user (I think?).

What would be the best way to build a script to do this? Do I have to remove the current build directory on the server in its entirety and then build it? Replace the already copied git repo? I'm new to all this, so I'm not sure if there is a much easier way to do this.

Thanks.